Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile)on project b: Fatal error compiling: error:
May seek anyone kind assistance on this issue?
I've installed jdk-21 and netbeans IDE 21. But, when I run the program, it appears the error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project b: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 21.0.2.


Under Environment Variable > System Variables > Path, I've added new path.

I've added JAVA_HOME as well.
I've tried as what I mentioned above. But, still got that error? What should I do? Tqvm. Appreciate for your help.

First have you tried to build on plain command line and before that mvn --version please post that output...furthermore the used version of the maven-compiler.plugin is old... upgrade your plugin versions... and do not post images...

Hi, do you mean type mvn --version on cmd? It stated: 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/download.cgi I searched, and saw that there's only this Maven Compiler Plugin 3.13.0, is it ok to install?

You have to configure the version in your pom file... not manually installing ... check all other plugin versions as well (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

Noted, tqvm. May I know are these codes in pom file correct? If Java 8, then should type 1.8 for the source & target, how about Java version 21? I installed jdk 21 & netbeans 21. As I see for the maven plugin, the latest one is 3.13.0 version released this year in March, so I modified to 3.13.0, may I know is that alright?


4.0.0
a
b
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 



commons-lang
commons-lang
2.2





org.apache.maven.plugins
maven-compiler-plugin
3.13.0

1.8
                    1.8





source & target 1.8 is as I checked on: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html                                                     I think I should put 21 for source & target since I installed java 21?

Please show the pom file...

The above three latest comments are the codes of pom file ya. Sorry that it exceeds the word limit, so I've to separate it into 3 parts, tqvm. Appreciate it

That are not the pom content...that does not help... full pom file... in your post...
